# okhttpUtils post a audio as params but throw java.net.ProtocolException: expected 1875 bytes but received 2067

Tags: android, okhttp, protocolexception

This is my code to uspost an audio as a params to my server,but sometimes it would work fail ,i don't know where is wrong ,who can help me or give me some suggestion ，thank u~

```
     OkHttpUtils.post(postUrl)
                .params("Filedata",new File(GlobalUtils.getRecordDirPath()
                        ,RECORD_TEMP_MP3))
                .execute(new JsonCallback<GradeSpeakingReportModel>(GradeSpeakingReportModel.class) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(GradeSpeakingReportModel gradeSpeakingReportModel, Call call, Response response) {

                    ....
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Call call, Response response, Exception e) {
                        super.onError(call, response, e);
                        ....

                    }
                });
    }
```

11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: expected 1875 bytes but received 2067
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1xStream.java:279)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okio.ForwardingSink.flush(ForwardingSink.java:39)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:218)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at com.lzy.okhttputils.request.ProgressRequestBody.writeTo(ProgressRequestBody.java:61)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:47)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
11-04 15:14:03.250 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at com.lzy.okhttputils.interceptor.LoggerInterceptor.intercept(LoggerInterceptor.java:40)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:33)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:120)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: expected 1875 bytes but received 2067
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSink.write(Http1xStream.java:279)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okio.ForwardingSink.flush(ForwardingSink.java:39)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:218)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at com.lzy.okhttputils.request.ProgressRequestBody.writeTo(ProgressRequestBody.java:61)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:47)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.255 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at com.lzy.okhttputils.interceptor.LoggerInterceptor.intercept(LoggerInterceptor.java:40)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:33)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:120)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-04 15:14:03.260 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-04 15:14:11.930 21739-21739/com.smartstudy.smartmark D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4955K, 36% free 42107K/65148K, paused 56ms, total 56ms

Comment: I solved it by copying the file before upload it.